# Why can I not retrieve CSS background property of DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the css background property of an element to a variable.

But when I log my var. to the console, it is an empty string.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5de0e69d/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var a1 = $("#adjust1");
    var a2 = $("#adjust2");
    var a3 = $("#adjust3");
    var a4 = $("#adjust4");
    var a5 = $("#adjust5");
    var b = $("#gradient");
    var c = $(b).css("background");
    var count = 0;
    $('.click').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id);
        count += 1;
        var rotate = count * 36;
        switch (id) {
            case "adjust1":
                console.log(c);
                break;
            case "adjust2":
                console.log(c);
                break;
            case "adjust3":
                console.log(c);
                 break;
            case "adjust4":
                console.log(c);
                 break;
            case "adjust5":
                console.log(c);
                 break;
        }

 });

    });
```

Comment: There's no html in demo or above. No way for us to replicate. Fiddle also throws errors. You can't animate all those properties either with JS. Use css transitions instead

Comment: no need to keep <script> tags on the js panel of jsfiddle. Also, what about the html/css content ?

Comment: fiddle is exactly the same ... no changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background` is a shorthand property. From http://api.jquery.com/css/:

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.

You may need to check `background-color`, `background-image`, etc.

Comment: I'm using background in my css though.

Comment: @Mark it's not relevant what you use to set a master property, it's relevant that it can't be retrieved as that master

Comment: @Mark: The shorthand is computed as though you manually set all of its longhands individually.

Comment: background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #1e5799 1%, #7db9e8 100%);

So what is the longgandle version of this?

Comment: @Mark: That would be `background-image`. In CSS, gradients are considered images.

Comment: Yep! Gradients are images that are created on the fly.